# app stuck with blackscreen after default.png

Tags: ios, screen, freeze, default.png

Hi my application gets stuck on a black screen after default.png and then nothing else is loaded . we updated a old project of xcode 3.0 to xcode 4 , and the flow at the begining is

appdelegate -->Window (bgcolor-black )-->Rooviewcontroller(bgColor-black) -->Main view(at end of init method by performslector for ad network loading ) .

Note: Its works fine for our devices but users are complaining of application get stucking in black screen or of UI get being unresponsive. Also its a window based application according to old template.

We are not able to get hold of the issue or the reason that mayb causing it please help..

following is the code

```
    mainViewControllerApp *objVC=[[mainViewControllerApp alloc] init];
    objVC.view.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    [self.window setRootViewController:objVC];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, is `init:` really your designated initializer for this view controller?

Typicaly, you either use `initWithFrame:` (if creating the view programmatically) or `initWithNibName:bundle` (if loading the view from a bundle).

If this view controller is *suppose to be* loading a view from a bundle, this could very well result in the behavior you're describing (the view controller doesn't know where the view is and the correct initializer is never called)...

Comment: hm.. it could not be the reason since init would initialize the controller , initwithnib is required only if we intent to initialize our view with nib, but that not the case. Also we do programmtically add a custom view to view controller.